# Erase remove idiom on a std::string with non-printable characters throws exception

Tags: c++, erase-remove-idiom

I am reading some text from another process through a pipe. The pipe returns the data to the variable `chBuf` but contains lots of non-printable chars. I tried to remove these non-printable characters using erase and remove but throws an exception. The program works without this erase remove line. What may I doing wrong?

```
 ReadFile(si->child_out_r, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
 string s(chBuf);
 s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !isprint((unsigned)c); }), s.end());
 cout << s;
```

Comment: If `chBuf` isn't null-terminated, you're in for a rough time.

Comment: Also, if nulls appear in your data (not at the end of the string) you won't be cleaning the part of the data after the first null.

Comment: @Dave any solution? I don't want it to throw. Should I truncate the string at the first occurrence of null char?

Comment: You could use the `string` constructor that takes the length: `string s(chBuf, dwRead);`  Now `s` may contain nulls, and it will have all the data in it.  ANd your cleaning process should work too.  Another option is to use `vector<char> s(chBuf, dwRead);`.

Comment: @Dave: `string s(chBuf, dwRead);` works like charm. Can you post t as answer? So that I can close the case. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data in your file may contain nulls (amidst other characters that you're interested in), or it is not guaranteed to have a null at the very end, then you need to tell `std::string` how much data it should use to build the string.  You do this with the `std::string( const char *, size_t )` constructor:

```
std::string  s( chBuf, dwRead );
```

The string cleaning process should work OK if you do that.